# Why do we use "part of the reason" and not "one of the reasons"?

Tags: phrase-usage

As the word reason is countable and one thing can have many reasons, I would imagine that saying "one of the reasons" is more logical than "part of the reason". However, many people (native and non-native speakers alike) tend to use the latter.

My questions are:

1- Is it correct to use "part of the reason"?

2- Is it correct to use "one of the reasons"?

3- If both are correct, is there any reason why "part of the reason" is more common?

Thanks

Comment: ***One of the reasons*** is a much more common expression: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=part+of+the+reason%2C+one+of+the+reasons&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpart%20of%20the%20reason%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20the%20reasons%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Both are used.  The choice depends in part on whether the "reasons" are (in a vaguely conceptual way) "countable" or not.  And, in part, it's simply an arbitrary choice on the part of the speaker.

Comment: Thanks Josh61. I think this trend shows that "one of the reasons" is much more common in written texts.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks. I guess I'll go with "one of the reasons" more often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1- Is it correct to use "part of the reason"?
```

Yes, because saying it like this suggests that this reason is only part of a whole reason. If it were the whole reason we could say something like "the only reason..."

```
2- Is it correct to use "one of the reasons"?
```

Yes, because saying it like this suggests that this reason is only 1 of many reasons. If it were the only reason we could say something like "the 1 and only reason..."

```
3- If both are correct, is there any reason why "part of the reason" is more common?
```

I don't think "part of the reason" is more common, but perhaps it is for you. The beauty of the English language is its diversity in using it.

Comment: Thanks Micheal. A quite comprehensive answer. And yes, having a choice usually leads to some nice diversity.

Comment: @MuhammedAlsayadi you're welcome, feel free to award the answer if it answered your question.